# Product of two integers of the form $x^2+my^2$ is of the same form.

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $x,y,a,b\in \mathbb Z$. Prove that there are integers $c$ and $d$
so that
\begin{equation*}
(x^2+y^2m)(a^2+b^2m)=c^2+d^2m.
\end{equation*}
I'm stuck, I took the product and got $x^2a^2+b^2y^2m^2+(a^2y^2+x^2b^2)m$ but the numbers in the parenthesis need not be squares. Thank you in advance.

Comment: See https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Brahmagupta-Fibonacci_Identity

Comment: This is the earliest case of Gauss composition of binary quadratic forms; you can look this up in various places, such as the book by Cox, Primes of the Form $x^2 + n y^2.$ The version of this that we use is actually due to Dirichlet, with the phrase "united forms" of importance; it turns out that Gauss's long description of what a composition operation should accomplish can be satisfied by 14 different operations. This observation is due to Bhargava.

Comment: Cox, especially page 49  http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-1118390180.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
(x^2+y^2m)(a^2+b^2m) &=  x^2a^2 +mx^2b^2 +m^2y^2b^2+my^2a^2 \\
&= x^2a^2 +m^2y^2b^2 +m(x^2b^2 +y^2a^2) \\
&= x^2a^2 \color{red}{ +2mxyab } +m^2y^2b^2  +m(x^2b^2 \color{red}{ -2xyab }+y^2a^2)\\
&= (xa + myb)^2 + m(xb-ya)^2
\end{align}$$

Giving $c=(xa + myb)$ and $d=(xb-ya)$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$x^2a^2+b^2y^2m^2+(a^2y^2+x^2b^2)m=(xa-bmy)^2+(ay+bx)^2m$$

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

$$\begin{align}(ax+mby)^2+m(ay-bx)^2
&=a^2x^2+2maxby+m^2b^2y^2+ma^2y^2-2maxby+mb^2x^2\\
&=(a^2+mb^2)(x^2+my^2)\end{align}$$

The easy way to remember it is the identity with $m=1$

$$(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)=(ac+bd)^2+(ad-bc)^2$$

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way(and the one that makes most sense to me) is:

$$x^2 + my^2 = (x+y\sqrt{-m})(x-y\sqrt{-m}) $$
$$(x^2 + my^2)(a^2+mb^2) = (x+y\sqrt{-m})(a+b\sqrt{-m})(x-y\sqrt{-m})(a-b\sqrt{-m})$$
$$ = ((ax-bym) + \sqrt{-m}(bx+ay))((ax-bym) - \sqrt{-m}(bx+ay))$$
$$ = (ax-bym)^2 + m(bx+ay)^2$$